# multiple application in Android manifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest, splash-screen

can we have more than one "application" in android manifest.xml
if so please provide some example.
the one application will start a service, and a wcf call in background and will show a splash screen and afterwords it will pass intent to a activity which is keep in another "application"

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

> application  >
>           . . .
>       /application>

application  >
        . . .
    /application>
        . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have one.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filec

> Only the manifest and application elements are required, they each must be present and can occur only once

Answer (score 0):

The definition of an "application" is kind of fussy for Android due to the concept of Activity. From your description, there's no reason why you can't do it using a few Activity's. If what you are asking is whether or not your application can have multiple launcher icons, then you can add

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

to multiple activity's.